# Azure Data Flow compare two string with lookup

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

I'm using Azure Data flow to do some transformation on the data but I'm facing some challenges.
I have a use case where I have two streams, these two streams have some common data, and what I'm looking for is to output the common data between these two streams.
I do matching data with some common fields(product_name(string) and brand(string)), I have not got ID.
to do the matching, I picked lookup activity and I tried to compare the brand  in the two streams, but THE RESULT IS NOT CORRECT because for example:

> left stream : the brand = Estēe Lauder

> right stream. : the brand = Estée Lauder

for me this is the same brand, but they have different text format, I wanted to use 'like' operator but lookup activity does not support it, I'm using '==' operator to compare.

is there a way to override this problem please ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Exists transformation instead of Lookup, you will have much more flexibility because you can use custom expressions including regex matching. Also, you can look at using fuzzy matching functions in the Exists expression like soundex(), rlike(), etc.

Comment: Yes, te Exist returns anly the right columns and not all the columns this is the problem

Comment: Exists will show columns from both left & right sides